# Symfony3: How to get sum of all payments when 3 entities are related

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've got three entities:

- Company
- Invoice
- Payment

It's related like: Company has Invoices and Invoice has Payments.

I want to get something like this:

Get all companies and get sum of all of payments amount from all invoices that company has.

What is the best way to do it?

Regards

Comment: create a query which will give you the sum - please show us are your current efforts

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom method in your repository, something like that:

```
public function getCompaniesAndPaymentsSum()
{
    $sql = "SELECT company.name, SUM(payment.value)
            FROM company
            JOIN invoice on invoice.company_id = company.id
            JOIN payment on payment.invoice_id = invoice.id
            GROUP BY (company.name)";
    $connection = $this->em->getConnection();
    $stmt = $connection->executeQuery($sql);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```